# How to post data with asp.net core/react

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I used the template in Visual Studio 2017 for asp.net core 2.0/react.js but could not manage to post data in the body.

The `id` from the url is filled correctly, but the string from the body is `null`.
I'm using IIS Express if it matters.

My code so far:

Server part:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Parts")]
public class PartsController : Controller
{



    // POST: api/Parts
    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public void Post(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        // breakpoint is hit.
        // id is set.
        // if I change "string value" to "dynamic value" I get an JObject.
    }
}
```

Client part:

```
private sendUpdates() {

    var payload = { "value": "2"}


    fetch('api/Parts/5',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        });

}
```

The request looks fine in the browser debug:

[image: browser debug info]

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but shouldn't you map the payload you send from the client to a type in your web-api? `{property: value}` from your client becomes a `class Something {
public string Property { get; set }
}`?

Comment: @user2236165 I do this for stuff from server to client. I don't think I'll have to do that for arguments. But I'm also not sure...

Comment: @user2236165 You we're right. At least introducing a class for the parameters worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Core API controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestingController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public IActionResult Test(string pl)
        {
            if (pl == null)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            PL plobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PL>(pl);
            return Ok($"Test Test a=={plobj.a} b=={plobj.b}");
        }
    }
```

C# Class to serialize

```
 public class PL
    {
      public string a { get; set; }
      public  string b { get; set; }
    }
```

ReactJs Part

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: "", loading: true};

        var PL = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        };
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("PoLos", JSON.stringify(PL));

        fetch('api/Testing/test',
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: data
            }).
            then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ text: data, loading: false });
            });

    }
```

I have to Note: Name in appending data in React part must be same AS name of variable in Core controller (ignoring case)

Comment: Can you please explain what `PoLos` is in `data.append("PoLos"...`?

Comment: It just a Nameing, it can be any.

Comment: You have an error in your example. `PoLos` vs `ps`. JS and C# must have the same name of parameter otherwise it doesnt work. Line `data.append("PoLos", JSON.stringify(PL));` and `public IActionResult Test(string pl)` ... if I fix it to `public IActionResult Test(string PoLos)` it will work.